# How can I multiply two matrices, one 2D by one 1D?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication

I know how to muliply two matrices with the same numbur of colums and rows. But how can I multiplicate two matrices, one bidmensionsional by one unidimensional, on Java using arrays?

e.g.:

```
{1,2,3}
{1,2,3}
{1,2,3}
```

X

```
{1,2,3}
```

How can I do this multiplication on Java?

Answer (score -1):

You can try it like this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < arr1.length; x++) {
    result[x] = arr1[x][0] * arr2[0] + arr1[x][1] * arr2[1];
}
```

[image]

The example will solve it like in the picture, I think.
`arr1` is the 2D array and `arr2` is the 1D array, I hope I could help you.